# Problem regex, How to handle multiple View URL with optional parameters with Search form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to learn Django since few weeks, and I'm completely lost at this point. I don't know much about regex, and I don't see where my mistakes are.

I build an app who makes research in different class fields. I created a first view (view.index_cleint) with templates and url. In the way to learn the management of URL with regex, I decided to make an other view (view.test_api) with just a different query filter. (I have 2 templates links to the 2 different views to display each the correct informations).

Here's the URL file with the regex:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', views.index_client, name='dashboard'),
    re_path('^search/(?P<param>\w+)/$', views.index_client, name='dashboard'),
    path('dash/', views.test_api, name='test_dash'),
    re_path('^dash/(?P<param>\w+)/$', views.test_api, name='test_dash'),
   ]
```

the two first urls are for my view 1 and to handle the search form.
The two lasts are for my second view and to handle the search form.

Here's the code of my first view:

```
def index_client(request, param='company_name'):
    print("test all")

    if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q']
        if query is None or query == '':
            query = ''
    else:
        query = ''

    list_param_query = ['company_name', 'email', 'status', 'id']

    if param not in list_param_query:
        param = 'company_name'
    url_param = param + '/'

    try:
        last_update_obj = UpdateDatabase.objects.latest('last_update')
    except UpdateDatabase.DoesNotExist:
        diff_date = None
        hours = 0
        minutes = 0
        seconds = 0
        print("No last_update in database")
    else:
        last_update = last_update_obj.last_update
        date_now = timezone.now()
        diff_date = date_now - last_update
        days, seconds = diff_date.days, diff_date.seconds
        hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
        minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
        seconds = seconds % 60

    try:
        customer_list = Client.objects.filter(
            Q(company_name__contains=query) | Q(email__contains=query)
            | Q(status__contains=query) | Q(first_name__contains=query)
            | Q(last_name__contains=query)).order_by(str(param))
        print(customer_list)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard.html', locals())

    print(customer_list.count())
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(customer_list, 1000)
    try:
        customers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        customers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        customers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    try:
        total_confirmed = Client.objects.filter(status="CONFIRMED").count()
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        total_confirmed = 0
        print("Error can't count customers")

    if diff_date is not None:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard.html', {'customers': customers,
                                                                  'total_confirmed': total_confirmed,
                                                                  'diff_date': diff_date, 'hours': hours,
                                                                  'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds})
    return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard.html', {'customers': customers,
                                                                  'total_confirmed': total_confirmed,
                                                                  'diff_date': diff_date})
```

And here the code of my second view:

```
def test_api(request, param='company_name'):
    print("test2")

    if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q']
        if query is None or query == '':
            query = ''
    else:
        query = ''

    list_param_query = ['company_name', 'email', 'status', 'id']

    if param not in list_param_query:
        param = 'company_name'
    url_param = param + '/'

    try:
        last_update_obj = UpdateDatabase.objects.latest('last_update')
    except UpdateDatabase.DoesNotExist:
        diff_date = None
        hours = 0
        minutes = 0
        seconds = 0
        print("No last_update in database")
    else:
        last_update = last_update_obj.last_update
        date_now = timezone.now()
        diff_date = date_now - last_update
        days, seconds = diff_date.days, diff_date.seconds
        hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
        minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
        seconds = seconds % 60

    try:
        search_1 = Q(status__contains="CONFIRMED")
        customer_list = Client.objects.filter(search_1 &
            Q(company_name__contains=query) | Q(email__contains=query)
            | Q(status__contains=query) | Q(first_name__contains=query)
            | Q(last_name__contains=query)).order_by(str(param))
        print(customer_list)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard_p1.html', locals())

    print(customer_list.count())
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(customer_list, 1000)
    try:
        customers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        customers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        customers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    try:
        total_confirmed = Client.objects.filter(status="CONFIRMED", priority=1).count()
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        total_confirmed = 0
        print("Error can't count customers")

    if diff_date is not None:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard_p1.html', {'customers': customers,
                                                                         'total_confirmed': total_confirmed,
                                                                         'diff_date': diff_date, 'hours': hours,
                                                                         'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds})
    return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard_p1.html', {'customers': customers,
                                                                     'total_confirmed': total_confirmed,
                                                                     'diff_date': diff_date})
```

In case here's the model I use for my views:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_open = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_open = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_confirmed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    CONFIRMED = 'CONFIRMED'
    WAITING = 'WAITING'
    OPEN = 'OPEN'

    MNT_STATUS = [
        (CONFIRMED, 'Confirmed'),
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
        (WAITING, 'Waiting'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        choices=MNT_STATUS,
        default=WAITING,
    )
```

The only difference between the first and the second view is a filter to get all customers of priority 1:

in the first view:

```
    try:
        customer_list = Client.objects.filter(
            Q(company_name__contains=query) | Q(email__contains=query)
            | Q(status__contains=query) | Q(first_name__contains=query)
            | Q(last_name__contains=query)).order_by(str(param))
        print(customer_list)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard.html', locals())
```

in the second view:

```
    try:
        search_1 = Q(status__contains="CONFIRMED")
        customer_list = Client.objects.filter(search_1 &
            Q(company_name__contains=query) | Q(email__contains=query)
            | Q(status__contains=query) | Q(first_name__contains=query)
            | Q(last_name__contains=query)).order_by(str(param))
        print(customer_list)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'maintenance/dashboard_p1.html', locals())
```

Before creating my second view test_api and adding the two lasts URLs everything was working fine, when clicking on my search form, I was redirected to my view 1 and the search was successful.

But since I add my second view every time I make a research from templates from the view 2 the results from the view 1 query are display.I don't get ONLY the priority 1 but all the objects

When I make a research from "127.0.0.1:8000/dash/" (view 2), I see a printf(2), which is in my second view, but the query is not respected and I get the result from view 1.

Did you see any mistake I made ?

Tx in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. If you go to `/dash/`, why would you expect it to go to view1? It clearly wouldn't match `/search/`.

Comment: Hello @DanielRoseman
I just edit my post.  Tell me if my explanation are better, sorry English is not my tongue language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems right. I think the problem is here `search_1 = Q(status__contains="CONFIRMED")`.

Please show us your Client model. (I'm sorry I can not leave a comment)

Comment: I just add in my post the model used for the different views :)

Comment: @0wly Try `search_1 = Q(status__icontains="confirmed")`

Comment: I try and I got the same problem .. :/